# search those records which have column value with & in it

Tags: php, mysql, select, ascii

I have a problem in my website, I'm trying to fetch some data from a table that has courses names. I search by the name of that course. some of the names contain '&' in them, for example "Formal Languages & Automata" and I need to fetch all the records related to this course.

When I try the below SQL statement, it fails in getting what I want:

```
   SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE course = 'Formal Languages & Automata'
```

The query searches for "Formal Languages " only and neglects the & and anything after it.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post how your query is constructed and how you are outputting the data? The ampersand itself doesn't have any special meaning in MySQL so just the presence or absence of it in a string couldn't cause any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that this could happen in is if you're passing the value you're searching by in a GET query string or a POST request body without [URL-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) it, thus when PHP receives the request, the part after `&` is considered the next variable in the request. In case you make the request from PHP, you need to use [urlencode()](http://php.net/urlencode) and if it's in Javascript, it's the [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the ampersand (`&`) character in your string:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE course = 'Formal Languages \& Automata'
```

Comment: This isn't Oracle, ampersand itself has no special meaning in MySQL strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **LIKE**

```
 SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE course LIKE 'Formal Languages%'
```

This statement will find every course that begins with 'Formal Language' and it can have any characters in the end.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

More about string comparsion can be found at link above. Also before puting some data to query you should escape it or use prepared statements and binding parameters which engines that have already escaping built in. For example mysqli, pdo.

Example **PDO**

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE course = :search');
$sth->bindParam(':search', 'Formal Languages & Automata', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
```

More info about PDO [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I was able to solve it by url encoding the variable passed in GET.